# java ArrayList about the result

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    result.add(temp);
    temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    temp.add(1, 3);
    result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
```

The result is [[1, 3], [1, 3]],  but I think it should be [[1, 2], [1, 3]], why?

Answer (score 5):

Follow comments

```
temp.add(1);  /aaded 1 
temp.add(2);  / added 2
result.add(temp);
temp.remove(temp.size() - 1); // removed index 1 that i.e removed 2
temp.add(1, 3);   // added 3 at the index 1 again.  now it is 1,3 
result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));  // And you are added a new array list again with temp
```

And if I understand correctly, you misunderstood the logic at

```
 temp.add(1, 3);
```

That means you are telling add the value  `3` at the index `1` in the list `temp` .

Answer (score 2):

Output is self explanatory.

Misconceptions

1.) `temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);`

This removes last element from `temp list` and since `temp list` is being referred inside `result` so it get referenced there as well.

2.)  `temp.add(1, 3);`

It will add the value 3 at the index 1 in the `temp list` .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(1);
        temp.add(2);
        System.out.println("Temp is : " + temp);

        result.add(temp);
        System.out.println("Result is : " + result);

        temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
        System.out.println("Temp is : " + result);
        System.out.println("Result is : " + result);

        temp.add(1, 3);
        System.out.println("Temp is : " + temp);

        result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        System.out.println("Result is : " + result);
    }
```

**output**

```
Temp is : [1, 2]
Result is : [[1, 2]]
Temp is : [[1]]
Result is : [[1]]
Temp is : [1, 3]
Result is : [[1, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update `temp` directly then all the references pointing to that `list` is also updated (in your case `result` list 1st index), that's why you are getting `[[1, 3], [1, 3]]` output.

You can use below code.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
temp.add(1);  //added 1 
temp.add(2);  // added 2
result.add(temp);

// creating new object and populating it with the values of temp.
ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<>(temp);

// or you can reinitialize temp with its previous values and then use it as you have done in your code.
// temp = new ArrayList<>(temp); 

temp1.remove(temp1.size() - 1);
temp1.add(1, 3); 
result.add(temp1);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not copy the values of temp into result but you are just giving a reference to temp.

By changing the reference you change the result.

To solve the problem, try this:

```
public void test1() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
    temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
    temp.add(1, 3);
    result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
}
```